# How to do to get the last insert of below laravel code?

Tags: laravel, find, sql-order-by

How to do to get the last insert of below laravel code?

```
$v_videos = VCategory::find($id)->videos->toArray();
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [timestamps](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#timestamps) for your models you can do this:

```
VCategory::find($id)->videos()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Otherwise you can still use the id (given its auto-increment)

```
VCategory::find($id)->videos()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

**Edit**

There's also a little shortcut for the `orderBy` part.

```
VCategory::find($id)->videos()->latest()->first();
```

Or

**without timestamps:**

```
VCategory::find($id)->videos()->latest('id')->first();

Thanks @Joseph Silber for `latest()`
```

Comment: You can use `latest()` and `latest('id')` instead. Just a nice little shortcut :)

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about that. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the reverse() method and fixed it.

VCategory::find($id)->videos->reverse()->toArray();

Thanks you.